# How can I save the contents of a textarea as a variable using javascript in an external document?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have tried, as many have suggested, saving a variable as the `.value` or `.innerHTML` of an ID, found by using `document.getElementById`. Here is all of my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>write</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="g.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="g.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="box">
    <textarea id="txt" placeholder="placeholder. type here.">text text</textarea>
</div>  
</body> 
</html>
```

and here is my javascript, currently meant to fire an alert that contains the text in the text area – right now that would be, `text text`:

```
function run(){
var txt = document.getElementById('txt');

alert(txt);}

run()
```

Right now, loading the page fires an alert with the text `Null` and adding `.value` after `getElementById('txt')` results in no alert. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your javascript is executing before the DOM is constructed.  When you load the JavaScript file in the `<head>` of the document, it is executed immediately, before the `<textarea>` tag has been created.

Try moving your script block below the textarea, just before the `</body>` tag.

Here's an example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsbcb/)

After the DOM is constructed you can use `getElementById` just as have and can access the contents of the textarea with the `value` attribute.  All of this is in the fiddle above.

Alternatively, you can wrap your `run()` method call with a library that provides an event when the DOM becomes ready.  jQuery's example would be:

```
$(function () {
  // code you want to execute when the DOM is ready.
  run();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function run() {
  var txt =  document.getElementById("txt").value;

  alert(txt);
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
            run();
 });
```

check this jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Xadgw/)

You are not getting textarea value because your javscript function is getting executed before there's value in DOM

or using javascript

```
function run(){
var txt =  document.getElementById("txt").value;

alert(txt);
}


window.onload = run();
```

More about [window.onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. So I take it that the added code – the last three lines – do not run the function until the page has been fully loaded?

Comment: yes window.onload event will fire only after page has been loaded

Answer (score 1):

The javascript below works in firefox.  In fact, if you click the `answer` button for this question, you can try it out in [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) on this very page...

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("wmd-input"); // #wmd-input is the text input where your answer goes...
alert( textArea.value );
```

Make sure you enter some text first, of course.

While you're at it, you should give jQuery a try:

```
alert( $("#wmd-input").val() );
```

Or better yet,

```
console.log($("#wmd-input").val());
```

Hope that helps.